# Problem with Unpickling and args with default values

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Character():

    def __init__(self):
        self.race = "Ork"
```

I create an instance and pickle it.

```
c = Character()

import pickle
with open(r'C:\tmp\state.bin', 'w+b') as f:
    pickle.dump(c, f)
```

When I try to unpickle it, everything works fine.
But what if I want to add another attribute to Character?
I go and to this:

```
class Character():

    def __init__(self):
        self.race = "Ork"
        self.health = 100
```

Let's say I want to unpickle the old version where we don't have the `health` attribute. If I just unpickle the data from the file, the object will not have the `health` attribute. To make it in a proper way, following what is written in "Effective Python" book, I need to introduce arguments with default values and bring the `copyreg` into play.

So, I do this:

```
class Character

    def __init__(self, race = "Ork", health = 100):
        self.race = race
        self.health = health

import copyreg 

def pickle_character(state):
    kwargs = state.__dict__
    return unpickle_character, (kwargs, )

def unpickle_character(kwargs):
    return Character(**kwargs)

copyreg.pickle(Character, pickle_character)
```

Now unpickling should work fine:

```
with open(r'C:\tmp\state.bin', 'rb') as f:
    c = pickle.load(f)
```

This code works fine, however, I still don't see in the `c` object our new `health` attribute.

The question is simple, why does it happen? Everything should work fine according to "Effective Python".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard behaviour for unpickling directly assigns the attributes - it does not use `__init__` or `__new__`. Therefore, your default arguments do not apply.

> When a class instance is unpickled, its `__init__()` method is usually not invoked. [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances)

Calling `__init__` may have side-effects, and may take additional, fewer or other parameters than attributes. This makes it an unsafe default. In effect, pickle uses `object.__new__(cls)` to create the instance and then updates its `__dict__`.

You must explicitly tell `pickle` to use `__init__` if you want to.

---

When using `copyreg`, you must pass it the [`constructor` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html#copyreg.pickle). Note that this does have a different signature than your `unpickle_character`.

Otherwise, your pickling function (`pickle_character`) statically defines the function used to unpickle. Since there is no constructor registered for the `Character` class and the old pickle does not include it, loading the old pickle does not call your constructor.

```
def pickle_character(state):
    kwargs = state.__dict__
    return unpickle_character, (kwargs, )
    #      ^ unpickler stored for *newly pickled instance*!
# no constuctor stored for *Character class* v
copyreg.pickle(Character, pickle_character)
```

---

It is easier to define [`__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) on your class. This directly receives the state, even from older pickles.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, race, health):
        self.race = race
        self.health = health

    # load state with defaults for missing attributes
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.race = state.get('race', 'Ork')
        self. health = state.get('health', 100)
```

If you know that `__init__` is safe and backwards-compatible, you can use it to initialise from the pickled state as well.

```
class Character:
    # defaults for every initialisation
    def __init__(self, race='Ork', health=100):
        self.race = race
        self.health = health

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        # re-use __init__ for initialisation
        self.__init__(**state)
```

Comment: So `pickle` will instead call `__new__`?

Comment: @C.Nivs It directly constructs the object, circumventing the class'  ``__new__`` as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi hmm... why signatures are different? I thought the author in "Effective Python" meant that we introduce a dict in the form of args with default values and so we can pass **kwargs.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "It is only invalid when used as a constructor" what do you mean by that? "Note that I cannot reproduce your error" - do you mean that on your machine my code unpickles the old version and you have an object with a newly added attribute in place?

Comment: @EngineerSpock I can reproduce the error now - I had incorrectly fixed your example code. Your *old* pickle only stores ``Character, {'race': 'Ork'}``, and your *new* pickle stores ``unpickle_character, {'race': 'Ork', 'health': 100}``. The old pickle only knows the class, while the ``unpickle_character`` function is part of (new) pickles only, *not* the class.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see, I missed the *picked instance* part of the docs, so neither `__new__` nor `__init__` *should* be called since that wouldn't make sense at the instance level

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "you must explicitly tell pickle to use __init__ if you want to." how can I do that? Can you fix my code to rely on this way of unpickling? Big thanks for your help!

Comment: @EngineerSpock I've added an example of using ``__init__`` to initialise from pickled state as well.